# Multiply Price and Quantity and Insert the value in total

Tags: c#

[image]

Hello, I want to multiply the value of price and quantity and set on the table total on my database. How can I populate this things on this code? I'm using c#

Comment: You can SQL "Insert" any calculated value you want, but the `Insert` statement you were showing in your picture does by design not seem to have a column for that multiplication. The SO concept by the way suggests to paste code as (formatted) text, not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (int.Parse(txtQty.Text) * price));
```

As a separate thought, should quantity be a decimal?  It could be possible to have a unit of measure in feet, meters, gallons, etc.